# Tomcat Servlet "Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/birt]]"

Tags: tomcat, servlets, birt

i'm trying to "start" a webapp in tomcat but when I press "start" in manager application tomcat(8.5 running on debian 8) answers:

> FAIL - Application at context path /birt could not be started
>   FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/birt]]

If i read the /logs/catalina.out i get the following warnings

> 20-Sep-2016 20:56:09.472 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/birt]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
>   at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:284)
>           at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
>           at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
>           at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
>           at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResource.getJarInputStreamWrapper(JarResource.java:47)
>           at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource.doGetInputStream(AbstractArchiveResource.java:218)
>           at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractResource.getInputStream(AbstractResource.java:93)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:154)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4997)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   20-Sep-2016 20:56:09.474 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/webapps/birt
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/birt]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

as anyone an idea of what is the cause of this problem?
thank you
Luca

Comment: Keep digging in the log files.  Depending on how you have it set up it may be in catalina.out or somewhere else but the error that caused your web application to fail is in one of them.  If this is a development system, you might consider stoping Tomcat, removing all of the old log files, and restarting - that minimizes the number of files you might be seeing.

Comment: Is possible that this kind of errors are generated when tomcat Is missing some libraries?

Comment: After hours of digging in log files i figured out that the version of software I was trying to install was bugged.   if it's helpful for somebody don't install the BIRT v4.6.0 because is going to drive you crazy ;)   everything worked when I installed 4.2.2